# if expression to find if text is in a field for a DictReader key

Tags: python, if-statement, import-from-csv

I would like to get the **if "172" in** statement to identify the addresses with 172 in them.  Thinking I must have syntax wrong on `"if "172" in {row["IP_ADDRESS_ZLOC"]}:"` but cannot find the solution.

```
import csv

pre_config = []

with open('ip_list.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        ip = {row["IP_ADDRESS_ZLOC"]}
        pre_config.append(
            f'1. MAKE TEXT FOR EVERY INSTANCE {row["IP_ADDRESS_ZLOC"]}'
        )
        if "172" in {row["IP_ADDRESS_ZLOC"]}:
            pre_config.append(
                f'  2. TRIGGER WHEN IP {row["IP_ADDRESS_ZLOC"]}'
            )
        if {row["IP_ADDRESS_ZLOC"]} == {row["DATA"]}:
            pre_config.append(
                f'  4. TRIGGER WHEN BOTH FIELDS MATCH {row["IP_ADDRESS_ZLOC"]} - {row["DATA"]}'
            )
        print(row)
print('\n')
print("\n".join(pre_config))
```

Here is the data in the OrderedDict and the results I'm getting:

```
OrderedDict([('IP_ADDRESS_ZLOC', '172.11.11.11'), ('DATA', 'public')])
OrderedDict([('IP_ADDRESS_ZLOC', '10.10.10.10'), ('DATA', 'private')])
OrderedDict([('IP_ADDRESS_ZLOC', '172.1.82.5'), ('DATA', '172.1.82.5')])
OrderedDict([('IP_ADDRESS_ZLOC', '10.27.57.55'), ('DATA', 'private')])
```

```
1. MAKE TEXT FOR EVERY INSTANCE 172.11.11.11
1. MAKE TEXT FOR EVERY INSTANCE 10.10.10.10
1. MAKE TEXT FOR EVERY INSTANCE 172.1.82.5
  4. TRIGGER WHEN BOTH FIELDS MATCH 172.1.82.5 - 172.1.82.5
1. MAKE TEXT FOR EVERY INSTANCE 10.27.57.55
```

The first and third lines should also have a line for `2. TRIGGER WHEN IP <IP`.

Comment: A nice improvement to your question would be: replace the wall of text by the **essential** information. Did you get an error? Then provide a [mre] and the complete error traceback. If the code runs, but doesn't output what you want, please include the actual vs expected output. Until then, sorry, but I won't even try to read all of this. Help us help you!

Comment: can you please also post your data, what is in the file, - it can be dummy data but at least the structure would help a lot...

Comment: Why did you use `if "172" in {row["IP_ADDRESS_ZLOC"]}:` and not `if "172" in row["IP_ADDRESS_ZLOC"]:`?

Comment: THAT'S IT!  Needed the {} everywhere else so was just mixed up on it.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
    if "172" in row["IP_ADDRESS_ZLOC"]:
        pre_config.append(
            f'  2. TRIGGER WHEN IP {row["IP_ADDRESS_ZLOC"]}'
        )
```

Answer (score -1):

I am able to get it to work when I change to:

```
    if "172" in "{}".format(ip):
        pre_config.append(
            f'  2. TRIGGER WHEN IP {row["IP_ADDRESS_ZLOC"]}'
        )
```

Is it necessary for me to create a variable to match to or is there a simpler way?